# Magento 1.9 turns 503 error on Stripe Webhook request

Tags: php, magento, stripe-payments, webhooks

Please help to clarify which side Magento1.9 or Server turns 503 error to stripe webhook in such cases:

> 1. Case 1: Successful payment -- web hook fails to create magento
>      orderes,
> 2. Case 2: cancelled subscription -- web hook is not
>      processed.  503 Error
> 3. Case 3: Successful payment - web hook
>      fails with 503

The access.log contains such lines (ip at the begining of line was changed for example): 
`-11.111.111.111 - - [26/Feb/2018:09:40:24 +0000] "POST 
/subscription/stripe/webhook HTTP/1.1" 503 7319 "-" "Stripe/1.0 
(+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"
-22.222.222.222 - - [26/Feb/2018:17:30:01 +0000] "GET /cron.php HTTP/1.1" 20 +0000] "POST /subscription/stripe/webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 3907 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"0 3444 "-" "Wget/1.15 (linux-gnu)"
-33.333.333.333 - - [26/Feb/2018:17:48:26 +0000] "POST /subscription/stripe/webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 3907 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"
-22.222.222.222 - - [26/Feb/2018:18:07:58 +0000] "POST /subscription/stripe/webhook HTTP/1.1" 503 7321 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)"`

So as you see sometimes it turns 200 sometimes 503. 
There is no maintenance.flag file. Site is working fine except named cases.
How to define what cause of such cases?

Also i got this error page

`Customer email is required
Trace:
0 - /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php(76): Mage::exception('Mage_Customer', 'Customer email ...')
1 - /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1122): Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer->_beforeSave(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
2 - /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
3 - /var/www/html/app/code/local/Blackbox/Subscription/controllers/StripeController.php(123): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
4 -  /var/www/html/app/code/local/Blackbox/Subscription/controllers/StripeController.php(18): Blackbox_Subscription_StripeController->paymentSucceeded(Array)
5 -  /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Blackbox_Subscription_StripeController->webhookAction()
6 -  /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('webhook')
7 -  /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
8 -  /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
9 -  /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
10 -  /var/www/html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
11 -  {main}`